# how to bind a functor with more than one argument to lua using luabind

Tags: luabind

If I want to bind a functor with one argument to lua using luabind, the following code could help:

```
struct vec
{
    int operator()(int a)
    {
        return a + 10；
    }
};
module(L)
[
    class_<vec>("vec")
        .def( self(int()) )
];
```

But how to bind a functor with more than one argument, for example:

```
struct vec
{
    int operator()(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        return a + b + c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `tag_function`.

http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind/docs.html#binding-function-objects-with-explicit-signatures